# From wsdl to services in python

Tags: python, django, soap, wsdl

I need to query a SOAP service wrote in Java from a web-application developed with Django.

To build a SOAP client I use the `Zeep` library. My problem is to understand which services expose the SOAP service, which parameters need to be passed to the `Zeep` client.

Is there a python library able to parse a `wsdl` file and build, for  example, an `sdk` to query the SOAP services. Any other ideas to solve this?

Comment: `suds` might do what you want..?

Comment: zeep ist perfectly able to parse WSDL, the first example in the documentation even uses WSDL (http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) -- maybe you should try explaining why using WSDL with zeep didn't work before searching for alternatives? (Also, having used suds in the past I'd strongly recommend staying with zeep, but that's just my opinion.)